# OneToOne relation with nullable to true and relation using primary keys

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have two entities with a OneToOne relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPLICATION_DEVICE")
public class ApplicationDevice implements Serializable {

[...]

    @Id
    public ApplicationDeviceKey getApplicationDeviceKey()
    {
        return applicationDeviceKey;
    }

    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationId", referencedColumnName = "applicationId",insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable = true),
    @JoinColumn(name = "deviceId", referencedColumnName = "deviceId",insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable = true), }
)
public ApplicationDevicePushInfo getDevicePushInfo() {
    return devicePushInfo;
}
```

and the other entity:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "APPLICATION_DEVICE_PUSHINFO")
 public class ApplicationDevicePushInfo implements Serializable {

 [...]
 @Id
public ApplicationDeviceKey getApplicationDeviceKey()
{
    return applicationDeviceKey;
}

 @OneToOne
@JoinColumns( {
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationId", referencedColumnName = "applicationId",insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "deviceId", referencedColumnName = "deviceId",insertable=false,updatable=false, nullable = false)}
)
public ApplicationDevice getApplicationDevice() {
    return applicationDevice;
}
```

The second entity could be null, and when I try to store my first entity I get an:

```
 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`malcom_dev`.`application_device`, CONSTRAINT `FK16A0C0451DC7C799` FOREIGN KEY (`applicationId`, `deviceId`) REFERENCES `APPLICATION_DEVICE_PUSHINFO` (`applicationId`, `deviceId`))
```

By default nullable is to true, so I thought it would be possible this relation.

There are another way to have to entities with a oneToOne relation without create new columns or tables, and allow nullable the second entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Hibernate but database exception. Looks like there is foreign key constraint on the  table.

It will work after you remove foreign key constraint.